# Orig DB = No Corruption, Backup/restore = Corruption?

Tags: sql-server, restore, corruption, dbcc-checkdb

We are setting up offline `DBCC CHECKDB`s on an offline server so we can still do our checks, but not interfere with production.

When we backup the Master DB and restore it (even directly on a local SSD on the same production machine) we get 36 corruption errors when we `DBCC CHECKDB` the restored DB (master_restore).

But when I `DBCC CHECKDB` the original master DB, I get no errors. Any idea?

```
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=12,depid=0,depsubid=0) was found in the system table sys.syssingleobjrefs (class=12).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=13,depid=1,depsubid=0) was found in the system table sys.syssingleobjrefs (class=13).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=60,depid=1,depsubid=0) was found in the system table sys.syssingleobjrefs (class=60).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=26,depid=1,depsubid=0,indepid=3,indepsubid=0) was found in the system table sys.sysmultiobjrefs (class=26).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=13,depid=2,depsubid=0) was found in the system table sys.syssingleobjrefs (class=13).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=60,depid=2,depsubid=0) was found in the system table sys.syssingleobjrefs (class=60).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=60,depid=3,depsubid=0) was found in the system table sys.syssingleobjrefs (class=60).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=60,depid=4,depsubid=0) was found in the system table sys.syssingleobjrefs (class=60).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=60,depid=5,depsubid=0) was found in the system table sys.syssingleobjrefs (class=60).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=26,depid=261,depsubid=0,indepid=3,indepsubid=0) was found in the system table sys.sysmultiobjrefs (class=26).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=26,depid=262,depsubid=0,indepid=3,indepsubid=0) was found in the system table sys.sysmultiobjrefs (class=26).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=26,depid=263,depsubid=0,indepid=3,indepsubid=0) was found in the system table sys.sysmultiobjrefs (class=26).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=26,depid=264,depsubid=0,indepid=3,indepsubid=0) was found in the system table sys.sysmultiobjrefs (class=26).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=26,depid=266,depsubid=0,indepid=3,indepsubid=0) was found in the system table sys.sysmultiobjrefs (class=26).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=26,depid=268,depsubid=0,indepid=3,indepsubid=0) was found in the system table sys.sysmultiobjrefs (class=26).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=26,depid=269,depsubid=0,indepid=9,indepsubid=0) was found in the system table sys.sysmultiobjrefs (class=26).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=26,depid=269,depsubid=0,indepid=10,indepsubid=0) was found in the system table sys.sysmultiobjrefs (class=26).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=26,depid=273,depsubid=0,indepid=3,indepsubid=0) was found in the system table sys.sysmultiobjrefs (class=26).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=26,depid=274,depsubid=0,indepid=3,indepsubid=0) was found in the system table sys.sysmultiobjrefs (class=26).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=26,depid=277,depsubid=0,indepid=3,indepsubid=0) was found in the system table sys.sysmultiobjrefs (class=26).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=26,depid=278,depsubid=0,indepid=3,indepsubid=0) was found in the system table sys.sysmultiobjrefs (class=26).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=26,depid=279,depsubid=0,indepid=3,indepsubid=0) was found in the system table sys.sysmultiobjrefs (class=26).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=26,depid=280,depsubid=0,indepid=3,indepsubid=0) was found in the system table sys.sysmultiobjrefs (class=26).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=26,depid=283,depsubid=0,indepid=3,indepsubid=0) was found in the system table sys.sysmultiobjrefs (class=26).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=76,depid=65536,depsubid=101) was found in the system table sys.syssingleobjrefs (class=76).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=76,depid=65536,depsubid=103) was found in the system table sys.syssingleobjrefs (class=76).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=76,depid=65536,depsubid=104) was found in the system table sys.syssingleobjrefs (class=76).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=76,depid=65536,depsubid=105) was found in the system table sys.syssingleobjrefs (class=76).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=76,depid=65536,depsubid=107) was found in the system table sys.syssingleobjrefs (class=76).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=76,depid=65537,depsubid=101) was found in the system table sys.syssingleobjrefs (class=76).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=76,depid=65537,depsubid=103) was found in the system table sys.syssingleobjrefs (class=76).
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=76,depid=65537,depsubid=107) was found in the system table sys.syssingleobjrefs (class=76).
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 32 consistency errors not associated with any single object.
Page (1:10) in database ID 13 is allocated in the SGAM (1:3) and PFS (1:1), but was not allocated in any IAM. PFS flags 'MIXED_EXT ALLOCATED   0_PCT_FULL'.
CHECKDB found 1 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors in table '(Object ID 99)' (object ID 99).
CHECKDB found 1 allocation errors and 32 consistency errors in database 'master_restore'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The master database is a special case. You will note that the corruption is in page 10 which is the config page. This is showing as corrupt because it is missing data when restored as a user database, instead of a master database for an instance.

Paul Randal wrote a post about this http://sqlmag.com/blog/my-master-database-really-corrupt